# Running code on the service event queue

Tags: android, service

I know I can run code on an `Activity's` UI thread by using `runOnUiThread()`. If I consider a `Service` to be an activity without user interface, how would I run code on the `Service`'s event queue?

Does this event queue even exist? I know a `Service` is not a thread, but what if I start an extra thread and want to run events in the `Service` how would I do that? I know *something* is running, because broadcasts are received and I can use `Handler`s.

For example in the following code:

```
class MyService extends Service {
    public doStuff = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // what to put here, to run code on the calling thread?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Thread t = new Thread(doStuff);
        t.start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create a Handler in the main thread of the service (e.g. in the 'onCreate' method) and post runnables from other threads. But what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it does not make sense to have access to the event queue from a service, since services are not meant to have any interaction with the user

Comment: @nitzanj I had a thread-related error because I was doing work on the service thread. I fixed it by using broadcasts, but I am not certain that is the correct solution.

Comment: @Blackbelt, okay, but what if I want to do stuff on my UI from a service? E.g. update a status?

Comment: service are not meant to interact with the UI. Activity and Fragment take care of the ui staff. You could broadcast an update event, and if the activity/fragment is available (i.e. is visible to the user), it can take care of it

Comment: @Blackbelt what about notifications? They also can be considered as UI (although I did not found any documentation whether it's legal to post them from background threads)

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev I just posted a `Notification` from another thread, and that works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Service` is running on the same thread as `Activity` (main thread) you can just create a `Handler` in `onCreate` (or wherever you want on the main thread) and post runnables to it:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable(){....})
```

Basically that means that `Activity` and `Service` are sharing the same event queue. Neither of your app components (`Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `ContentProvider`) receives lifecycle events on any other thread except main.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that as it is possible that a service can run apart from an activity, or I can have multiple activities in my application?

Comment: @BartFriederichs I find it hard to elaborate why you **can't** have multiple activities. That's possible and perfectly fine that you might have multiple activities, services, receivers, providers to run (or rather exist) at the same time and share the same event queue.

Comment: Ok, is it safe to say there is one event queue per application? And is this a separate thread apart from the UI thread?

Comment: @BartFriederichs by default yes - one queue per app. I'm not 100% sure how situation changes if you split your app into multiple processes (processes, not threads). In general UI works on the same thread (event/main thread), but as for Android 5.0 there is additional RenderThread (which exists for optimisation purposes and does not affect you directly as a developer).